# How can I run xampp on ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I have installed `XAMPP on`ubuntu 13.04` and its running but I don't know where to run it next time,there was no shortcut created on desktop. So how can I run it when I use my computer again after shutdown?

Comment: The preferred way of installing apache, mysql and php is [using the standard packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) - it's easy to install and you get the updates automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy and everything is explained on the XAMPP official web site.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

You can use different parameters for XAMPP on Linux: just substitute `start` with `stop`, `restart`, `startapache` (starts only the Apache web server), `stopapache`, `startmysql` (starts only the MySQL database), `stopmysql`, etc.

You can read more here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#378

Answer (score 0):

The command to run XAMPP is : *sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start*

You can create a symbolic link to access it easier :
*sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp /usr/bin/lampp*

Then the command *sudo lampp start* will be able to launch XAMPP.